# merge lines of a txt file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, vi

I invoke a program from shell script and it creates an output file
with this format:

```
aaaaa\
bbbbb\
ccccc\
```

I would like to change this to:

```
aaaaabbbbbccccc
```

In VI editor I can just do `ggVGJ` and then replace all \ with "".
But I want to get this done via a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\\\n//g; s/\\$//' file
```

Another way using `awk`, may give you better performance:

```
awk '{ sub ("\\\\$", ""); printf "%s", $0 } END { print "" }' file
```

Results:

```
aaaaabbbbbccccc
```

---

Explanation:

The `awk` solution removes the trailing backslash (via substitution) and printf's each line (without a newline character). `END` (which is executed at the end of the script) then prints a newline character. This is superior to the `sed` solution, which creates a label called `a` and appends the next line of input into the pattern space. `$!ba` means 'if not at the last line of input, branch to label `a`'. The first substitution then removes each backslash and newline character from the pattern space. The second substitution removes the last, trailing backslash. This solution should be fast for small files, but probably won't be any faster than the `awk` for the same file. Although ... it was faster to write.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the `abc`s could be anything and the file is really long

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Added an `awk` solution. HTH.

Comment: The `awk` solution worked. Thanks. Can you please update your answer with some explanations.

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Explanation added. Please let me know if you need a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `sed` and `tr`:

```
sed 's/\\$//' < sample.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

If you want to add a newline too, you can add an `echo` at the end:

```
sed 's/\\$//' < sample.txt | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

If you want the whole thing to be a one unit, for example to use in a `... && ... || ...` construct then you can group the two steps like this:

```
{ sed 's/\\$//' < sample.txt | tr -d '\n'; echo; }
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. When I pipe the output to the same file like this:
`sed 's/\\$//' < sample.txt | tr -d '\n' | cat > sample.txt` and then open it in vi i get the `[noeol]` flag. So the last line of the file does not have a newline

Comment: You could also do: `sed 's/\\$//' file | tr -d '\n'; echo`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using pure bash:

```
$ cat file.txt 
aaaaa\
bbbbb\
ccccc\
$ { cat file.txt ; echo; } | while read line; do echo $line; done
aaaaabbbbbccccc
$
```

This works because the bash `read` command actually deals with the \ continuation automatically (use the -r switch to `read` to disable this behavior).  The `echo` after the `cat` is necessary for this example because the last line of your sample text ends in `\`, so the read command doesn't think it has got to the end of a line and doesn't output anything.  The `echo` just inserts an empty line at the end of the stream to clean this up.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this solution is the smallest:

```
$ cat tmp.txt
aaaaa\
bbbbb\
ccccc\

$ cat tmp.txt | tr -d "\\\r\n"
aaaaabbbbbccccc
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution. I guess you are replacing "\" and linebreak with "".

Comment: I'm simply deleting the characters \, \r and \n from stdin. TR's flag '-d' causes the deletion of the searched characters instead of replacing them with a second set of chars.

Answer (score 2):

try this line;

```
awk -F'\\\\$' '{printf "%s", $1}END{print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a ***really*** ugly hack, but you could use the [gcc preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

```
 $ cat file.txt 
 aaaaa\
 bbbbb\
 ccccc\
 $ cat file.txt | gcc -xc -E -P -w - | grep .
 aaaaabbbbbccccc
 $
```

Why is this risky?  If your input text happened to contain preprocessor directives, then they would get interpreted, resulting in a mess.

Answer (score 1):

One with `awk` and `sed` :

```
sed 's/\\$//g' file | awk '{printf "%s", $1}'
```

`sed` command removes the slash at the end of the line. `$` denotes the end of the line after a slash. Since `slash` is considered as a meta character in `sed`, you need an extra `\` to escape it. piping the output of sed to `awk printf` prints multiple lines in one. `$0` represents the entire line.

Comment: @iamauser: Not sure why this has been upvoted, but you should never write a printf statement without a format specification; especially when printing arbitrary strings with unknown content.